# Set column value depending of condition with JSLink

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jslink

**Entire JS**

```
(function () {
    var oFldCtx = {};
    oFldCtx.Templates = {};

    oFldCtx.Templates.Fields = {
        "Estatus": {
            "View": overrideStatus
        },
            "Cumplimiento": {
               "View":overrideCumplimiento
             }
    };

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(oFldCtx);
})();

function overrideStatus(ctx) {

    var sStatus = ctx.CurrentItem.Estatus;
     var sIconFileName = "";

switch(sStatus){
case "0":
sIconFileName= "cero.png"
break;
case "1":
sIconFileName= "uno.png";
break;
case "2":
sIconFileName= "dos.png";
break;
case "3":
sIconFileName= "tres.png"
break;
case "4":
sIconFileName= "cuatro.png"
break;
default:
break;
}

if(sIconFileName == "") return sStatus;

var sWebUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
var sIconSrc = sWebUrl + "/SiteAssets/" + sIconFileName;
var sImgTag = "<img id='" + ctx.CurrentItem.ID + "' ";
sImgTag += "src='" + sIconSrc + "' ";
sImgTag += "onclick ='callEditForm(this)' ";
sImgTag += "/>";

return sImgTag;
}

  function overrideCumplimiento(ctx) {
         var date = new Date();
         var currentServerDateTime = date.format("dd/mm/yyyy");
         var sCumplimiento = ctx.CurrentItem.Cumplimiento;
         var sCumplimientoInicial = ctx.CurrentItem.Fecha_x0020_Compromiso_x0020_Ini;


      if(currentServerDateTime < sCumplimientoInicial){
       ctx.CurrentItem.Cumplimiento = "Yes"
      }else{
       ctx.CurrentItem.Cumplimiento = "No"
      }


        }
```

Problem is into   `function overrideCumplimiento(ctx)`

It just don´t throw `yes` or `no` value on column. I debbug it and it pass correclty but just don´t place values in column

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that while you are setting your `Cumplimiento` field value on the `ctx.CurrentItem` object, that's not really the way rendering override functions work.

Rendering override functions need to **return the HTML that you want rendered to the page.**

So your `overrideCumplimiento` function should look something like:

```
function overrideCumplimiento(ctx) {
    var date = new Date();
    var currentServerDateTime = date.format("dd/mm/yyyy");
    var sCumplimiento = ctx.CurrentItem.Cumplimiento;
    var sCumplimientoInicial = ctx.CurrentItem.Fecha_x0020_Compromiso_x0020_Ini;

    var htmlToRender = "<div class='cumplimientoDiv'>";

    if (currentServerDateTime < sCumplimientoInicial) {
        htmlToRender += "Yes";
    } else {
        htmlToRender += "No";
    }

    htmlToRender += "</div>";

    return htmlToRender;
}
```

Now, I've added some extra stuff there by actually putting your Yes or No value inside a `div`, and giving it a class so you can apply custom styling if you want to.  That's all really extra.  At the simplest level, you could just return the "Yes" or "No" strings, like so:

```
if (currentServerDateTime < sCumplimientoInicial) {
    return "Yes";
} else {
    return "No";
}
```

Here is a great primer on [the basics of Client Side Rendering](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views).

The key thing you are missing is that your function needs to return a string representation of the HTML you want rendered on the page.  If you don't return anything, nothing will get rendered.

Comment: You´re right, I use return statement and it works. Thank you!